# Refresh Recycler View By Clicking A Button In Another Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am having two Fragments FragmentA and FragmentB inside and activity , both Fragments contains recyclerview with custom layout, now how can i refresh FragmentB's recycler view by clicking on a button which is placed in FragmentA's recyclerview???

Comment: add some code here what you have tried as of now

Comment: You can use interfaces to get the work done. Take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Comment: add some relevant code

Comment: Solved It With Interface, Thank You All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment A will communicate to hosting Activity on button click. The Activity will notify the Fragment B to refresh its recyclerview.

You communicate with hosting activity with the help of interface.

Answer (score 0):

create instance of fragment B and then call refresh method from fragment A

Comment: @BhavikParmar if you found this answer helpful. please make a thumbs up and selection.